# Samsung Galaxy S Duos GT-S7582

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Good Day to all I need help, after flashing the stock room of Samsung Galaxy S Duos GT-S7582 my phone turn to black screen help please how to fix this ...???[image: Need Help Please...]

Comment: Most likely the ROM you've flashed is not for the same model of phone that you have. Check again the model number written on the phone and the model number the ROM is for. Note that Samsung often releases different models of phone under the same marketing name.